# Raster calculator multiple expressions

Tags: raster, spatial-analyst, map-algebra

i have the following rasters: soilrisk, slope, rainfall

How can I create an expression that meets the following conditions?

```
(Soil risk = 1 and Slope > 7 and Rainfall < 800) OR
(Soil risk = 1 and Slope >= 3 and Slope <= 7 and Rainfall >= 800) OR
(Soil risk = 2 and Slope > 7 and Rainfall >= 800)
```

I tried using ''or' as an operator which appears to be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the Map Algebra [operators](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/spatial-analyst/mapalgebra/working-with-operators.htm) and [complex statements](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/spatial-analyst/mapalgebra/building-complex-statements.htm) documentation:

- `==` is the **equals** operator.
- `&` is the boolean **and** operator.
- `|` is the boolean **or** operator.
- you need to put `()` parentheses around each expression component.
- your layer names need to be double quoted if the rasters are layers in the map and you're using this expression in the raster calculator (this doesn't apply if the rasters are `arcpy.Raster("path/to/raster")` objects and you are using the expression in python).

E.g. assuming those rasters are layers in the map and you're using this expression in the raster calculator:

```
(("Soil risk" == 1) & ("Slope" > 7) & ("Rainfall" < 800)) |
(("Soil risk" == 1) & ("Slope" >= 3) & ("Slope" <= 7) & ("Rainfall" >= 800)) |
(("Soil risk" == 2) & ("Slope" > 7) & ("Rainfall" >= 800))
```